# How do I redirect user to a dynamic page that displays the data he/she input in a form in Django?

Tags: django

I've just started learning Django, and ran into a problem. 
So I'm trying to make a user-specific page that shows the information of each user which he/she has input in the beginning. I have a form `InputUserForm` in ModelForm. 
Below is my function in views.py, which I intended to let the user input his/her information in url '.../inputuserinfo' and then trying to redirect him/her to a page that shows the information he/she input.

```
def inputuserinfo(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = InputUserForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("usermain/"+"%i" %UserInfo.authuser_id)
```

*authuser is a ForeignKey connected to the User, in my model.
Obviously I'm having trouble in the `return` part. As mentioned earlier, what I was trying to do was as soon as the user submits the form, a dynamic page with the information he/she has input would show up. 
I have usermain.html file, and `path('usermain/<int:id>', ...)` in my urls.py, but I cannot figure out what the problem is.

I'm not sure if this is clear enough for you to understand, but this is the best I could explain with my limited knowledge in Django :(
I very much appreciate your help! :)

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: @Ejaz No, I get this error : <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor%20object%20at%200x000001EC366AD2C8>

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace.

Comment: @Ejaz I'm sorry, what exactly do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: Complete exception log that you would see on the terminal or in the logs